# How would you represent this logic in models and migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This has probably been asked but I am not even sure how to phrase this suitable for querying.

I wish to call `user1.friends` (user1 is an instance of the User model) which returns a list of users who all include user1 as one of their friends.

I am not sure where to even start with this one.

What would be my columns for the friends table? Should there even be a friends table?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use this [RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association)

models/user.rb:

```
has_many :friendships
has_many :friends, :through => :friendships
has_many :inverse_friendships, :class_name => "Friendship", :foreign_key => "friend_id"
has_many :inverse_friends, :through => :inverse_friendships, :source => :user
```

models/friendship.rb

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User"
```